# Supress Ansible warning (at least for aptitude install)

Tags: shell, ansible

How can I install aptitude package without ansible warning:

```
TASK [... : APT: Install aptitude package] ********************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Could not find aptitude. Using apt-get instead
```

my install code looks like:

```
- name: "APT: Install aptitude package"
  apt:
    name: aptitude
#  vars:
#    ACTION_WARNINGS: false << DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce (ansible 2.7.9, Ubuntu 18.04). Without aptitude installed the play installed aptitude without any warning. (localhost: ok=2 changed=1  unreachable=0 failed=0)

Comment: @VladimirBotka Hello, using Ansible from official Ansible repo (ansible 2.8.1) with Debian 9, both with default config, of course with aptitude purged.

Comment: Hello, just to be sure both environment [ANSIBLE_ACTION_WARNINGS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#action-warnings) and `action_warnings = false` in the [default] section of ansible.cfg does not  work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed (specifically) for the aptitude install:

```
- name: "APT: Install aptitude package"
  apt:
    name: aptitude
    force_apt_get: yes
```

based on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.8/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py#L1059

Answer (score 6):

Or use `module_defaults` in your [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html), if you do not want to pollute your system with aptitude:

```
---
- hosts: ...
  module_defaults:
    apt:
      force_apt_get: yes
  tasks:
    - ...
```

Comment: Good alternative! As long as the `aptitude` can be installed once I still prefer it to install as all packages relies on standard enviroment and any unusual configuration typically breaks something in the long term...